# Protected within this context c++

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with inheritance I guess.

Here is the class from the header file:

```
class Single : public Combination{
public:
    Single(Card* card);
};
```

Here is Combination initialized in the .cpp file:

```
Combination::Combination(Card** cards, CombinationType type, int numberOfCards){
    this->cards = cards;
    this->numberOfCards = numberOfCards;
    this->type = type;
}
```

And here is the Single class in .cpp file and the one giving me the error:

```
Single::Single(Card* card){
    cards = new Card*[1];
    cards[0] = card;
    Combination(cards, SINGLE, 1); //<- this context
}
```

The error says: 'Combination::Combination(Card**, CombinationType, int)' is protected within this context, however from the header file isn't Single able to access Combination?

EDIT: Thank you both for the quick and informative responses! Unfortunately I can only checkmark one of you but I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a base class' constructor from inside a derived class' constructor body, like you are trying to do.  It can only be called from the member initialization list.  So you are going to have to change the way you allocate your array, eg:

```cpp
class Single : public Combination{
private:
    Card* myCards[1];
public:
    Single(Card* card);
};

Single::Single(Card* card)
    : Combination(myCards, SINGLE, 1)
{
    myCards[0] = card;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
class Single : public Combination{
private:
    Card* myCard;
public:
    Single(Card* card);
};

Single::Single(Card* card)
    : Combination(&myCard, SINGLE, 1)
{
    myCard = card;
}
```

If the array must be allocated dynamically before calling the base class constructor, then you can use a helper, eg:

```cpp
class Single : public Combination{
public:
    Single(Card* card);
};

Card** CreateCardArray(Card* card)
{
    Card** cards = new Cards*[1];
    cards[0] = card;
    return cards;
}

Single::Single(Card* card)
    : Combination(CreateCardArray(card), SINGLE, 1)
{
}
```

Or, you can simply do this, assuming `Combination::cards` is not `private` in `Combination` and thus is not inaccessible to `Single`:

```cpp
Single::Single(Card* card)
    : Combination(new Cards*[1], SINGLE, 1)
{
    Combination::cards[0] = card;
}
```

Or, you can specify the input `card` directly in the `new[]` statement:

```cpp
Single::Single(Card* card)
    : Combination(new Cards*[]{card}, SINGLE, 1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to call the base constructor for your child object. The way you do that is with field initialization list:

```
Single::Single(Card* card)
    : Combination(new Card*[1], SINGLE, 1) {
    cards = Combination::cards;
    cards[0] = card;
}
```

Notice I've also switched things around a little.

I'm passing the `Combination` constructor a new `Card` pointer array address and then assigning the child `cards` member to that pointer we just passed (by grabbing it from the parent `cards` member).